# How to use local assets in a Electron Forge project?

Tags: typescript, webpack, electron, electron-forge

I'm currently using Electron Forge to develop a testing desktop application.

I want to use an image located in my project, for example into `./src/assets/images/main.png`
I tryed to import this image using an `<img />` tag but it does not work.

- I'm using typescript template
- I'm using react typescript

The following code below represent my simple desktop application.

```
import React from "react";
import { Typography, Image } from "antd";

const { Title, Text } = Typography;

const Index: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div className="w-full flex flex-col justify-center gap-4">
      <Title className="text-center font-bold">Bienvenido</Title>
      <Text className="text-center text-sm">
         Utiliza <Text keyboard>ctrl</Text>+<Text keyboard>k</Text> para abrir
        el menú de herramientas disponibles
      </Text>
      <Image src="../static/main.gif" width={300} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Index;
```

As you can see the `<Image src="../static/main.gif" width={300} />` not work and trigger the following error:

[image]

I tryed to search some examples around internet but I haven't clear how to make this.

Thank you for your help.